# How instance variable are related to class variable in python

Tags: python

```
class myclass(object):
    i=0
    def increase(self):
        self.i+=1
        print('increased value:', self.i)

if __name__=='__main__':
    m=myclass()
    m.increase()
```

Here is a class variable and `self.i` is instance variable , on executing i get o/P as 1.

But if  comment class variable `i` I get an error

```
self.i+=1
AttributeError: 'myclass' object has no attribute 'i'
```

what is the relation between class variable `i` and instance variable `self.i` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class variable is a variable which can be changed by all instances of your class. You call it by [class_name].[variable_name]

For Example:

```
class myclass(object):
    i=0
    def increase(self):
        myclass.i+=1
        print('incresed value:',self.i)

if __name__=='__main__':
    m=myclass()
    k = myclass()

    k.increase()
    m.increase()
    m.increase()
    m.increase()
    m.increase()
    k.increase()
```

results in

```
incresed value: 1
incresed value: 2
incresed value: 3
incresed value: 4
incresed value: 5
incresed value: 6
```

An instance variable on the other hand (like you have it) can only be accessed by the instance which created it (with self.[variable_name]).
To access a variable, the variable first needs to be instantiated. Like

```
a+=5
```

would create an error while

```
a = 0
a+= 5
```

would not

In your example the instance variable is not specificly instantiated. But because of the class variable (i=0) python automatically instantiates the instance variable (i) with the value of the class variable. (because class and instance variable have the same name)

In other words:

When in your example the class variable
    i=0
is removed python does not know what value your instance variable 
    self.i
should have in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that you are shadowing the class variable with a member variable.

See what happens when you instanciate another myclass-object and add a few printouts to your code:

```
class myclass(object):
    i=0
    def increase(self):
        myclass.i+=1
        print('incresed value:',self.i)

if __name__=='__main__':
    m=myclass()
    n=myclass()
    print("m.i=", m.i)
    print("n.i=", n.i)
    m.increase()
    print("m.i=", m.i)
    print("n.i=", n.i)
```

The output is now:

```
m.i= 0
n.i= 0
incresed value: 1
m.i= 1
n.i= 0
```

You see that you incremented the value of the i-member of m, but not of n. This is because **self** (like **this** in c++) always refers to the current object instance. If you update your code to the following, you are actually incrementing the class variable:

```
def increase(self):
    myclass.i+=1
    print('incresed value:',self.i)
```

And the output changes to the following:

```
m.i= 0
n.i= 0
incresed value: 1
m.i= 1
n.i= 1
```

Like Guillaume Jacquenot already stated in his answer, if you'd like to use member variables, it is advisable to initialize them in __init__(). In your case, the interpreter ist just using the class variable with the same name when it can't find a member variable, and in the same line initializing a member variable (with identical name i). If you comment out the class variable, you're trying to increment a variable which does not exist yet, hence the interpreter error.

Answer (score 0):

You use the following statements to declare a constant inside your class. `i` is not supposed to be modified later.

```
class myclass(object):
     i=0
```

You can access it with

```
 value = myclass().i
```

If you want a counter, you declare it in the constructor `__init__`, and increase it in a method

```
class myclass(object):
    def __init__(self): 
        self.counter = 0
    def increase(self): 
        self.counter += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is the lack of definition of `i` object after you remove the class variable.
The `i=0` statement is the only definition. It is the same with any other variable, nothing special happens here:

```
i+=1
```

yields the same error if you put it in main or anywhere. In order to do the increment `+=` you need to have the object declared first.

You can do:

```
class myclass(object):
def increase(self):
    self.i=0
    self.i+=1
    print('increased value:', self.i)
```

which makes no sense, but illustrates the issue, i think.